# Research for Video Length for Math Videos

Tags: undergraduate-education, videos

I'm looking for any references that exist for what a good video length for an online math class should be.

I am aware of these three papers but these are basically only for MOOCs - I'm looking for something in a mathematics class that's required - Ideally measuring long term learning but at this point anything is welcomed.

- Effective educational videos By Cynthia J. Brame, CFT
  https://www.lifescied.org/doi/10.1187/cbe.16-03-0125
- How Video Production Affects Student Engagement:An Empirical Study of MOOC
  Video - Guo et al., 2014
  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.714.195&rep=rep1&type=pdf
- Understanding In-Video Dropouts and Interaction Peaks inOnline Lecture Videos

  - Guo et al., 2014
    https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/90413/Miller_Understanding%20in-video.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

EDIT: I'm looking at the university [undergrad particularly] level. Yes I agree that static videos usually aren't best for learning (but say for algorithm demonstration; I find a video to be vastly more effective and efficient than a long prose describing the algorithm as both a learner and as an educator).

Comment: I don't know about research on videos, but there is plenty of research on people's attention spans. You would definitely want to go shorter than that.

Comment: There seems to be an implicit assumption here that noninteractive videos are an appropriate way to provide instruction (as opposed to written material and interactive video). I certainly wouldn't agree with that assumption, except maybe for exceptional topics where, e.g., you're showing an animation of the behavior of a PDE using fancy graphics. Could you also edit to say what age or educational level this is for? I don't think the answer is the same for kindergarten as for grad school.

Comment: Unless a video has really nice animations [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) narrated with licked-out voiceover, I'd prefer a written course to to a video. Talking heads are boring.

Comment: Maybe the [TED's 18-Minute Rule](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140313205730-5711504-the-science-behind-ted-s-18-minute-rule/) works for math classes.

Comment: I don't think this is for mathematics specifically, nor is it about video length, but it's about interactivity in videos. http://www.ijello.org/Volume13/IJELLv13p215-228Geri3902.pdf

Comment: I've been putting together one of my courses for the fall, online because of covid. I've been having various friends check it over. One who works for a corporate training company said they keep videos to 6-8 minutes. Again, not research but it seemed like a good guideline to me. 

Maybe there is no research...

Answer (score 1):

This data from [Wistia](https://wistia.com/learn/marketing/optimal-video-length) supports several of the comments:

---

[image: Engagement]

---

This chart is not specialized to mathematics.
Likely the attention-span constraints are pretty much universal, independent of content (but not independent of interactivity).

Comment: With text-based material, I think "dropout rate" would be higher with math because math can be incredibly dense.  So I would guess it's the same with video.  I don't have any data to support that, although I do know that with my youtube videos that I make on math, the drop out rate is fairly high(but that could just be my fault).